# how to display the user data after login in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

i created a user login page with database using SQLite, my requirement is to provide the information of the particular usr to provide the information to user after logged in and allow him to modify the details. please help me..

thanks in advance..

Comment: elaborate more....and with some snippets and wat exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Actually i am looking for the code to to show the particular user details when he logged in, i created database using SQLite and successfully registering the users and log in the user, what exactly am saying is if u open your profile in google, your details will be visible  and you can modify it, in the same way i need to provide the feature to the users in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to implement a small form that allows people to update their details and save them.

Your form will need to check provided user details against your database in order to authenticate them, and if they're authenticated should query the database for the fields that you want and display them to the user. When the user clicks your save button you will need to updated those fields and commit the changes.

For a good introduction to using `SQLiteDatabase`s in Android including reading and writing values, take a look at the quick [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) as well as the [guide to using databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db). For your buttons and user input, see the [Common Tasks and How To Do Them in Android](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html) page.